# Methods of solving nonlinear systems of equations derived from combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to find a way to generalize the expression of polynomials of degree $n-1$ such that
$$
k_1+k_2x+k_3x^2+k_4x^3+\dots+k_nx^{n-1}=\frac {k_1}{k_n}+\frac{k_2}{k_n}x+\frac{k_3}{k_n}x^2+\frac{k_4}{k_n}x^3+\dots+x^{n-1}
$$
$$
=(\lambda_1+x)(\lambda_2+x)(\lambda_3+x)(\lambda_4+x)\dots(\lambda_{n-1}+x)
$$
My goal is to find an expression for $\lambda_i$ in terms of $k_i$, and I've more or less doing this by induction (I think that's the word for it; I'm an engineer, not a mathematician). I started with a polynomial of degree 4 and have come up with the following system of equations:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{k_4}{k_5}&=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4 \\
\frac{k_3}{k_5}&=\lambda_1 \lambda_2+\lambda_1 \lambda_3+\lambda_1 \lambda_4+\lambda_2 \lambda_3+\lambda_2 \lambda_4+\lambda_3 \lambda_4\\
\frac{k_2}{k_5}&=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3+\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_4+\lambda_1 \lambda_3 \lambda_4+\lambda_2 \lambda_3 \lambda_4\\
\frac{k_1}{k_5}&=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \lambda_4\\
\end{aligned}
\end {array}
\right) 
$$

I theorize that if generalized to a polynomial of degree $n-1$, the system will be:

$$
\left(
\begin {array}{c}
\begin {aligned}
\frac {k_{n-1}}{k_n}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i\\
\frac {k_{n-2}}{k_n}&=\lambda_1 \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \lambda_i+\lambda_2 \sum_{i=3}^{n-1} \lambda_i+\dots+\prod_{i=n-2}^{n-1} \lambda_i\\
\frac {k_{n-3}}{k_n}&=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \sum_{i=3}^{n-1}\lambda_i+\lambda_2 \lambda_3 \sum_{i=4}^{n-1}\lambda_i+\dots+\prod_{i=n-4}^{n-3}\sum_{i=n-2}^{n-1}\lambda_i+\lambda_{n-1}\prod_{n-3}^{n-2}\lambda_i \\
&\vdots\\
\frac{k_1}{k_n}&=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_i
\end {aligned}
\end {array}
\right)
$$

If anyone knows of any way I could go about solving the system of equations or taking some other approach to the problem, your input would be very much appreciated.

Comment: These are known as the Vieta relations

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!